# Merge dataframe with a key value that is contained within a string in a separate dataframe

Tags: r

```
employee <- c('John','Peter', 'Gynn', 'Jolie', 'Hope', 'Sue', 'Jane', 'Sarah')
salary <- c('VT020', 'VT126', 'VT027', 'VT667', 'VC120', 'VT000', 'VA120', 'VA020')

emp <- data.frame(employee, salary)


benefit <- c('Health', 'Time', 'Bonus')
benefit_id <- c('VT020 VT126 VT667 VA020', 'VT667', 'VT126 VT667 VT000')

ben <- data.frame(benefit, benefit_id)
```

Above we have to dataframes, one contains names and a unique ID, the other contains a category and a list of unique IDs.

What is the most efficient way to merge the `ben` dataframe with the `emp` dataframe such that we get the appropriate benefit assigned to each employee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # tidyr
ben %>%
  mutate(benefit_id = strsplit(benefit_id, "\\s+")) %>%
  unnest(benefit_id) %>%
  left_join(emp, ., by = c(salary = "benefit_id"))
#    employee salary benefit
# 1      John  VT020  Health
# 2     Peter  VT126  Health
# 3     Peter  VT126   Bonus
# 4      Gynn  VT027    <NA>
# 5     Jolie  VT667  Health
# 6     Jolie  VT667    Time
# 7     Jolie  VT667   Bonus
# 8      Hope  VC120    <NA>
# 9       Sue  VT000   Bonus
# 10     Jane  VA120    <NA>
# 11    Sarah  VA020  Health
```

Depending on your needs, you may also prefer a different join. For instance, use a `full_join` if you want all pairings, where `NA` in `employee` indicates a benefit sans employee.

FYI: if you are running R before 4.0, then you might have `factor`s in your data. To fix that, just convert the factor columns with `as.character` first. (This can be determined with `sapply(ben, inherits, "factor")`.)

Comment: This works for me as long as `benefit` (in OP question, `ben`) is a `tibble` but not a `data.frame` (which makes the columns `factors` unless you set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`; `tibble` won't convert them to factors by default). Perhaps a note indicating that `benefit` should be a `tibble` would be helpful (my test was on R 3.5.2, so a newer version may have different results).

Comment: If it's a factor for you, then you must be on an older version of R: in R-4, the default changed to `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. But if that's an issue, all it takes is a call to `as.character` for each relevant column and the problem goes away :-)

Comment: I know how to resolve it, I just mentioned it as others may have run into it. At least it is mentioned in the comments. Either way, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(emp)
ben_long <- setDT(ben)[, list(benefit_id = unlist(strsplit(x = benefit_id, split = " "))), by = benefit]
merge(x = emp, y = ben_long, by.x = "salary", by.y = "benefit_id", all.x = TRUE)


    salary employee benefit
 1:  VA020    Sarah  Health
 2:  VA120     Jane    <NA>
 3:  VC120     Hope    <NA>
 4:  VT000      Sue   Bonus
 5:  VT020     John  Health
 6:  VT027     Gynn    <NA>
 7:  VT126    Peter  Health
 8:  VT126    Peter   Bonus
 9:  VT667    Jolie  Health
10:  VT667    Jolie    Time
11:  VT667    Jolie   Bonus
```